# What are the returned status code of `cdk diff`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm trying orchestrate next executed commands based on the result of the command `cdk diff`. Like so:

```sh
if cdk diff; then
  echo has no differences
else
  echo has differences
fi
```

Although this always prints *has no differences*. This is confusing to me because according to [aws-cdk docs](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/aws-cdk/README.md#cdk-diff) *This command returns non-zero if any differences are found.*

Comment: Your above code is fine - make sure `cdk diff` actually does have differences

Comment: It has. I am 100% since the actual differences are printed to `stdout` right before the _has no differences_

Comment: What shell are you running this in?

Comment: zsh. Can you point me one that works so I can verify?

Comment: What return code are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the --fail flag should fix it for you

```
if cdk diff --fail; then
  echo has no differences
else
  echo has differences
fi
```

See the "Toolkit Reference" Documentation at the bottom of this URL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html.

The documentation for CDK diff states the following:

```
      --fail   Fail with exit code 1 in case of diff   [boolean] [default: false]
```